# Unable to return value from img.onload

Tags: javascript

trying to get dimenstions (e.g. 600x300) from an image using javascript. I am not sure how to return the data because it's not working. Do I need a callback, and how  ?

```
<script>
function getMeta(url){   
    var img = new Image();
    var res = img.onload = function(){
        var ret = this.width+'x'+ this.height;
        alert(ret);
        return ret;
    };
    img.src = url;
    return res;
}
var meta = getMeta('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg');
alert(meta);
</script>
```

Comment: `getMeta` returns before the `onload` function fires. You'll need to use a promise or other async workflow.

Comment: @certainPerformance , it is but it also isn't, IMO the response below was perfect perhaps with your link included. I don't think this needed to be tagged as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getMeta` is finished before `onload` function. You need to use a Promise or a callback. Example with callback below:

```js
function getMeta(url, cb){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        var ret = this.width+'x'+ this.height;
        console.log(ret);
        cb(ret);
    };
    img.src = url;
}
getMeta('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg', function(meta){
  console.log('got meta', meta);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I think your answer plus the link to the other thread was perfect.. I got it working thanks to your help.